# How do i add a shape-file to a map in python dash?

Tags: python, python-3.x, plotly, plotly-dash

I want to create a choropleth of the Chicago neighborhoods using a shape file that i got from the city website.

I tried looking into the map box from the dash documentation but its not clear how to do that and the dash documentation says nothing about custom shapefiles for it.